# How to check request to API is from Chrome extension

Tags: java, node.js, google-chrome-extension, request

I am doing a Chrome extension project and I only want to limit request to my API using Chrome extension only. So I want to check API incoming request is it from Chrome extension, and I do not use any database.

Currently, I only thought of just sending a header with string and if API saw the header string, it will knew it is request from Chrome extension. Is there any better way or secure way?

Any advice?

Comment: Your approach of adding a custom header to your API requests from the Chrome extension is a reasonable and simple way to identify requests originating from your extension. However, keep in mind that headers can be manipulated by clients, so this method isn't foolproof.

Comment: @PrajilK hi, thanks, since there is a risk of clients manipulating client, do you have any more secure method of doing it?

Comment: @James what you're asking is an extremely hard problem.  It would either need to involve things like cryptographic signing *with a key no user can access on their own machine* or additional layers of network security and isolation.  Consider for a moment you're essentially asking to disallow someone the use of their own hardware.

Comment: Your method is not secure because any extension can add these headers. Instead, use temporary tokens.